# Terminology for cumulative vs non cumulative functions on timeseries data

Tags: naming

Say you had some (contrived) timeseries data like:

```
time   |  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |  5  |
temp 1 |  3  |  3  |  4  |  4  |  5  |
temp 2 |  2  |  2  |  2  |  2  |  2  |
...etc
```

Is there a particular terminology for functions that go across the rows (cumulative) vs the columns (point in time)?

For example, the sum of temp 1 across all the time periods is 19 (cumulative) but perhaps the max temp at time 3 is 4 (point in time).

Comment: I think the term you're looking for is "aggregate function".

Comment: From my understanding, the term "aggregate function" could be applied to both examples (a sum function and a max function are both aggregations) but is there general terminology to distinguish an aggregation function applied across many time periods vs an aggregation of many readings at a particular point in time (regardless of what the actual aggregation function is)?

Comment: @EmiPhil, I suspect the distinction is a little too specialised to have its own established name. You could try and work with "timerange" and "instantaneous" aggregates, it being implied in context that an instantaneous aggregate must work across an axis other than time (here, the 'sensor' axis), and that a timeseries aggregate surely works across (at least...) the time axis, but the possibility of an aggregate that works across both axes and all data (or some subset of rows or columns) would still remain to be distinguished. (1/2)

Comment: Also there is no reason, generically in other contexts, why a cross-sensor aggregate could not be cumulative - for example, if each measures the output of an individual machine, and the instantaneous total output is desired - or that a cross-time aggregate could not be non-cumulative (such as finding peak output of a specific machine over time). Many well-known aggregates can be seen fundamentally as composites of simpler aggregate operations and scalar operators (such as a mean average, being a sum divided by a count), and so don't fit into a simple schema. (2/2)

Comment: Okay, got it. Thanks for the information!